# NEITHER, EXCEPT ......, NOR

Tags: neither-nor, except

> Inside their house, approval should ***NEITHER*** be given, ***EXCEPT*** in very
>   special circumstances, for the ITEM A, or for ITEM B, ***NOR*** for ITEM C,
>   or for ITEM D

Is the following accurate?

- Approval **should *not*** be given to Item C, Item D
- Approval **should *be*** given to Item A, Item B

Comment: The entire sentence is a syntactic nightmare. In particular, the parallel structure of  of the *neither-nor* construction is wrong. It should be: *neither be **given** nor* ***something***. But it doesn't follow that pattern. I suspect it should read something like this: *In their house, approval should never be given (except in very special circumstances) for items A , B, C, or D.*

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford, much appreciate the reply! I was scratching my head over the "Except"

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Should read:

"Inside their house, approval should NEVER be given, EXCEPT in very special circumstances (for the ITEM A, ITEM B, ITEM C, or for ITEM D). "

or

"Inside their house, approval should NOT be given, EXCEPT in very special circumstances, for the ITEM A,  for ITEM B, for ITEM C, or for ITEM D. "

Comment: I have a slightly different interpretation, which takes into account the use of "neither" and "nor", although the sentence is, even so, horribly unclear. I read it as "In their house ITEM A and ITEM B may be approved only under exceptional circumstances while ITEM C and ITEM D may never be approved under any circumstances." As I said, it's still horrible.